# How to save changes to a file opened in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, files, editing

As it required root access to edit, I've opened a init.txt file using `sudoedit`, but I don't see how to save my changes. I also see lots of things like `^X` instructions at the bottom of the terminal which I'm clueless about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> to Exit. You will then be asked if you want to save.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> for Save and Exit

---

The notation for short-cuts is as follows: Control-key sequences are notated with a caret (^) symbol and can be entered either by using the Control (Ctrl) key or pressing the Escape (Esc) key twice.  Escape-key sequences are notated with the Meta (M-) symbol and can be entered using either the Esc, Alt, or Meta key depending on your keyboard setup.  Also, pressing Esc twice and then typing a three-digit decimal number from 000 to 255 will enter the character with the corresponding value.

---

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in nano to open the built-in help.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`^` is a common abbreviation for `Ctrl`. The editor you're using is nano, and you can find more documentation about it here: http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nano.html#Editor-Basics.

That said, if you have another editor you prefer (e.g. the graphical Gedit editor, or vim), just indicate that using the EDITOR environment variable:

`EDITOR=gedit sudoedit /etc/passwd`

You could make this "permanent" by exporting EDITOR with the desired value in your `~/.bashrc` file.